# How can I un-merge two accounts?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

About a month ago, I was logged in to Stack Exchange on either Stack Overflow or Game Dev SE. Then my brother came along, jumped on the computer, and thought he logged me out. But he actually clicked on "my logins" on my profile page:

---

[image: my logins]

---

Then he got here:

---

[image: add more logins]

---

For some reason, he clicked on "add more logins." I have no idea why.
When he did, he arrived here:

---

[image: add login]

---

Does this look familiar? It looks just like the login screen. He logged in with facebook or Google. Since then, our accounts have been merged. If you go to the [accounts tab on my profile](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/4306/dan-the-man?tab=accounts) and click on [AVP](https://video.stackexchange.com/users/815/caleb), [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/9452/caleb-pendergast) or [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/1258/caleb-pendergast), you'll see that his account is now my account, and vice versa!

I have e-mailed support about this, but they haven't responded. **What can I do to unlink our accounts?**

Comment: When you say "his account is now my account" - is there now only one account? Did there used to be two? If so, can you tell me what the old one might have been called?

Comment: Yes, there is only one account now. There used to be two. It was his name: Caleb Pendergast

Answer (score 4):

The only thing you can do is to email the support as you did, because they are the only ones who can do anything to revert the account merge.

I can understand why the account has been merged (I don't think the accounts are automatically merged, but that is another topic). Having the same OpenID account used on two different SE accounts could be the signal that the two accounts are used from the same person, or two people are sharing with each other the information about their SE accounts.

Answer (score 1):

To deassociate the login, just click the `X` to the right of that particular OpenID.

I don't think this will untangle any activities that were done with that account.  I can't speak to whether anyone could or would do that by hand for you.

Comment: I've tried that many times. But unfortunately, When I delete it, it will deletes the OpenID, but all the accounts stay connected. It will only remove his OpenID as an option for logging in.

Comment: @Dantheman As kiamaluno pointed out, then support is your only option.  I imagine they get a lot of requests for help, so give it on the order of days not hours.

Comment: I gave the on the order of weeks.

Comment: @DantheMan - Since it looks like you have a small enough number of posts for a manual un-merge to be feasible, you might consider creating new accounts in the meantime to minimize the amount of work for the team.  Merging your resurrected account with a temporary account is about a 4-click process for any mod, I don't think that the process you're requesting is nearly as streamlined.

Comment: @dantheman I'm not sure what to tell you.  See if a dev or other staff responds to this question, but you could try emailing again if it's been weeks.  Make certain, though, that your accounts were merged accidentally and not administratively.